# How to print to locally connected thermal printer from shared hosting without opening print dialogue

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, escpos

I am working on Laravel pos software in which there is a receipt printer module. I used escpos-php from GitHub it works perfectly on localhost because it uses kernel mode to send the print to USB connected thermal printer. But when I deployed on shared hosting it is not working. I checked this issue on the given Github repo. It is written there :
https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php

**Server-side printing is viable if the server can get to the printer. Here are some ways it could work:

1-Run your server on the LAN instead, and read the section above about printing over the network

2-Set up a VPN so that your cloud-hosted server can also access the LAN

3-Expose the printer via some other secure tunnel to the server, via SSH or TLS

Please do your own research to determine how these may apply to your setup- the escpos-php issue tracker is not a place where you should be requesting network support.**

I could not find any solution out of the 3 given above. So I searched and found a javascript client-side tool JSPrintManager which would be perfect for me but the license is required which is 250$...

https://www.neodynamic.com/articles/How-to-generate-and-print-raw-ESC-POS-commands-from-Javascript/

Now, suggest to me what should I do. I am stuck at it. Thank you

Comment: hey buddy did you find how to solve it? Im looking for something similar, I have a thermal printer in my network and its exposed through internet with port-fowarding, 
So Im needing any javascript library able to send a pdf receipt to print directly skipping the prompt to the user, just clicking print btn and then just cut the receipt output